# Powershell Forms: Two Buttons open the same sub-form

Tags: forms, powershell

I am beginning to learn how to create Tools with PowerShell. I have started the creation of what I like to call my Main Hub, where all my other forms will be located at the click of a button. I have a problem with the two buttons I have created. When I click on the Unlock an Account button, it opens my Account Unlock form. When I click on the Create a Distribution List button. It opens my Account Unlock form. Here is what I have written:

```
#Add in Forms Controls
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

#Image for Background and Top left icon.
$Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("C:\Users\myname\Desktop\FormRepository\Images\imagesFJA8GNHA.jpg")
$Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\Powershell.exe")
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",18)

#Begins creation of the form
$MainHub = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$MainHub.Icon = $Icon
$MainHub.Text = "My Name Forms - - - Apple Release"
$MainHub.BackgroundImage = $Image
$MainHub.BackgroundImageLayout = "Stretch"
$MainHub.Width = 1000
$MainHub.Height = 700
$Title = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Title.Font = $Font
$Title.Text = "What do you want to do?"
$Title.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1,1)
$Title.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(275,35)
$MainHub.Controls.Add($Title)

#Button Clicks
$BtnClick1 = {start-process powershell.exe '& C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Form Repository\Child Forms\UnlockADAccount.ps1'}
$BtnClick2 = {start-process powershell.exe '& C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Form Repository\Child Forms\DistributionList.ps1'}

#End Button Clicks

#Buttons
$AcctUnlock = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$AcctUnlock.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1,40)
$AcctUnlock.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,35)
$AcctUnlock.Text = "Unlock an Account"
$AcctUnlock.Add_Click($BtnClick1)
$MainHub.Controls.Add($AcctUnlock)
$CreateDistroGroups = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CreateDistroGroups.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1,80)
$CreateDistroGroups.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,35)
$CreateDistroGroups.Text = "Create a Distribution List"
$CreateDistroGroups.Add_Click($BtnClick2)
$MainHub.Controls.Add($CreateDistroGroups)
#End Buttons

#Displays the Form.
$MainHub.ShowDialog()
```

I've tried changing the variables around and renaming them for the button clicks. I've tried removing the Account Unlock Form code entirely so that only the distribution lists form exists in the form. Even then the Create Distribution list button opens the account unlock form. Any idea where I am going wrong with the creation of these buttons?

Comment: Hmmm--just replaced your script names with simple `script1.ps1` and `script2.ps1` and this worked fine.  Are you sure that you didn't accidentally overwrite your dist list script with the unlockaccount script?

Comment: I just double checked to make sure I didn't do that, and they are the correct scripts. I'm going to run the forms on a different machine to determine if I have something stuck.